# Running setTimeout() or setInterval() asynchronously

Tags: javascript, synchronous

Is it possible to execute `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` **synchronously** so that further execution that depends on its callback will not cause a `not defined` error?

```
intv = window.setInterval(function() {

    // do some stuff
    doSomeStuff();

    // kill interval when stuff is done
    if (stuffIsDone)
        window.clearInterval(intv);
}, 10);

// dependent on "stuff" being done
// I want this to execute only after intv is cleared
doMoreStuff();
```

I don't want to put every consecutive call inside of a timeout to check `if (typeof someStuff != 'undefined')`

*Yes, I do understand that this will cause a delay in loading and possible the UI.  The intervals will be extremely small and inconsequential.*

**EDIT...** Alright, what I'm ultimately trying to do is dynamically add a number of javascript files dynamically, by only including a single javascript file.

ie.:

```
// auto include all javascript files
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="include.js"></script>
```

This works by requesting the JSON list of javascript files from the server via AJAX.  It loops through the list and adds the scripts dynamically to the DOM.

**The catch:**

If I add the scripts using `setInterval`, they are sometimes added *after* the `onLoad` event fires, depending on the current computational load of the machine executing the code.  So, when I call functions from one of the files `onLoad`, it causes an error (because at the time of execution, the function didn't exist)

If I add the scripts inside of a `while` loop, the dynamically added scripts to do not execute and the internal references between the scripts are invalid and error out.

So, the question really is: **without using `setInterval` and `typeof` on every call**, how do I dynamically add scripts reliably so that dependent code doesn't attempt to execute before the depended-upon scripts are loaded?

Comment: No, that's not how they work.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `doMoreStuff()` right after the `clearInterval` in the `if (stuffIsDone)` block?

Comment: @AaronDufour: yes, this is a very simplified example of what I need to accomplish.  `doMoreStuff()` is only demonstrative of many other functions that will called from other scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Refactoring setInterval-based Polling](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2013/02/04/refactoring-setInterval-polling/) and consider converting your `setInterval` to a `setTimeout` and use a Promise to execute `doMoreStuff()` after `stuffIsDone` is true.

That article is from 2013, so consider [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) (using a [polyfill for ES6-style Promises](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) for older browsers) instead of jQuery's or Underscore's implementation.

Answer (score -1):

You can run a `while` loop and keep track of the system time if you want to block the JavaScript thread for a fixed period of time.

For example:

```
var startMillis = Date.now();
while (Date.now() - startMillis < 10);
```

Note that no other code will run during this period. JavaScript is single threaded.

Don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but this seems a little strange :)

Comment: D'oh, of course, a `while` loop.  I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: isn't this going to spin CPUs at 100%? :X

Comment: @sleepycal, yes, but there's no way of running it synchronously as OP asks. The only way is to spin-wait, which will use 100% CPU for the 10ms in question. Obviously this has problems, but it's the only way I know of to answer the question. As I said, it's a strange problem to have so the answer may be to actually re-think the problem and come at if differently.

Comment: And it'll only spin one CPU (or more precisely, one thread). JS is single-threaded.